# Adding decorations using MaterialCalendarView binding library in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using the [MaterialCalendarView](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149615/discussion-between-ryalis-and-york-shen) library in my Xamarin.Android application, which works well for the most part except that I am unable add a span decoration to the calendar.

- [Documentation and example for span decoration](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/DECORATORS.md#examples)

Here is my code:

```
public class Calendar : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Calendar);

            MaterialCalendarView calendar = FindViewById<MaterialCalendarView>(Resource.Id.calendarView);
            calendar.SetSelectedDate(Java.Util.Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.Locale.English));

            List<CalendarDay> dates = new List<CalendarDay>();

            CalendarDay a = CalendarDay.From(2017, 7, 10);
            CalendarDay b = CalendarDay.From(2017, 7, 15);
            CalendarDay c = CalendarDay.From(2017, 7, 9);
            CalendarDay d = CalendarDay.From(2017, 6, 1);

            dates.Add(a);
            dates.Add(b);
            dates.Add(c);
            dates.Add(d);

            //calendar.Post(() =>
            //{
            //    calendar.AddDecorators(new EventDecorator(Android.Resource.Color.HoloOrangeLight, dates));
            //});

            calendar.AddDecorators(new EventDecorator(Android.Resource.Color.HoloOrangeLight, dates));

        }
    }

class EventDecorator : Java.Lang.Object, IDayViewDecorator
{
    private int color;
    private List<CalendarDay> dates;

    public EventDecorator(int color, List<CalendarDay> dates)
    {
        this.color = color;
        this.dates = dates;
    }

    public void Decorate(DayViewFacade view)
    {
        view.AddSpan(new DotSpan(5, color));
    }

    public bool ShouldDecorate(CalendarDay day)
    {
        //return dates.Contains(day);
        return dates.Exists(e => (e == day));
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is not working? What error(s) do you get?

Comment: @MarcBruins There are no errors; the calendar is just not decorated

Comment: The effect you want achieve is add a black spots under the day you have added in the `CalendarDay` ?

Comment: @YorkShen Yes, that's right

Comment: @Ryalis, have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am unable add a span decoration to the calendar.

The problem is that your `ShouldDecorate` always return false when you use `dates.Contains(day)` or `dates.Exists(e => (e == day))`.

It will compare `HashCode` firet so it will always return false, modify your code like below can solve this problem :

```
if (dates[0].ToString() == day.ToString() || dates[1].ToString() == day.ToString() || dates[2].ToString() == day.ToString() || dates[3].ToString() == day.ToString())
{
      return true;
}
else
{
       return false;
}
```

Effect like this :

[image]

Comment: The issue still remains.

Comment: @Ryalis, change your color and try again : `calendar.AddDecorators(new EventDecorator(this, Color.Red, dates))`.