# how do I make a custom textview that has dots?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, drawing, custom-view

Im trying to do a calendar, and I want to show the user some sort of info about what event is stored in a specific day. and I was thinking of using small dots with the color they picked for the event, but I can't seem do find a way to do it, if at all possible...
I have this: [image: calendar without dots]
and I wanted something like this: [image]

can someone help me, or give me a tip on how to do so?

Comment: The TextView is just a textview right? But for the dots, I guess you need a transparent Canva which is the facility android provides for custom drawings and shapes on the screen.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xamarin but in native android you can do it like this: let the `TextView` have a bottom Drawable (use one of the `setCompoundDrawables...()` methods). Use some white Drawable with the desired number of dots and apply a color filter before setting it as bottom drawable (using [setColorFilter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#setColorFilter(int,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode)) ) . Don't forget to call `mutate()` on your Drawable before setting the filter

Comment: @0X0nosugar Can I make multiple dots with different colors with that approach?!

Comment: For example, having a red dot, a blue dot, and a green dot?

Comment: Yes, if you build a layer-list drawable with one dot per layer

Comment: and then I just have to make them visible one at the time right?!

Comment: Exactly (and if you find no other way of making them invisible, remember #00000000 also describes a color ;-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using third-part library [material-calendarview](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) to implement this feature, it provide a [DayViewDecorators](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/DECORATORS.md#examples) class to customize individual days:

- Set custom backgrounds
- Set custom selectors
- Apply spans to the entire day's text

  - We provide `DotSpan` which will draw a dot centered below the text
- Set dates as disabled

Since you are using `Xamarin.Android`, you could use this java library in your `Xamarin.Android` project via [Binding a Java Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/).

By the way, someone else has done this work for you: https://github.com/NAXAM/materialcalendarview-xamarin-android-binding, you could directly install it in [nuget package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEcPI.png).

### Simeple usage

Use it in `XAML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_custom_date_picker"
        app:mcv_selectionColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:mcv_showOtherDates="other_months"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your code:

```
public class CalendarActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_calendar);

        MaterialCalendarView calendar = FindViewById<MaterialCalendarView>(Resource.Id.calendar_view);
        calendar.SetSelectedDate(Java.Util.Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.Locale.English));

        List<CalendarDay> dates = new List<CalendarDay>();

        CalendarDay a = CalendarDay.From(2018, 11, 10);
        CalendarDay b = CalendarDay.From(2018, 11, 15);
        CalendarDay c = CalendarDay.From(2018, 11, 9);
        CalendarDay d = CalendarDay.From(2018, 11, 1);

        dates.Add(a);
        dates.Add(b);
        dates.Add(c);
        dates.Add(d);

        calendar.AddDecorators(new EventDecorator(this, Color.Red, dates));
    }

    class EventDecorator : Java.Lang.Object, IDayViewDecorator
    {
        private int color;
        private List<CalendarDay> dates;

        public EventDecorator(CalendarActivity calendarActivity, int color, List<CalendarDay> dates)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.dates = dates;
        }

        public void Decorate(DayViewFacade view)
        {
            view.AddSpan(new DotSpan(15, color));
        }

        public bool ShouldDecorate(CalendarDay day)
        {  
            //return dates.Contains(day);   
            //Has issue when using the above code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193268/adding-decorations-using-materialcalendarview-binding-library-in-xamarin-android/45207338#45207338

            if (dates[0].ToString() == day.ToString() || dates[1].ToString() == day.ToString() || dates[2].ToString() == day.ToString() || dates[3].ToString() == day.ToString())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEteE.png).

Comment: Well, it does do what I want, but right now I don't have enough time to implement it on my project, since I only have a few days left, when I come back to it again (I dunno when) I will definitely give it a try, thank you!